# get data from a row onclick based from button's row on laravel 4.2

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-4

i have this table that outputs a set of records in my view file here is what it looks like
[image: My table]

what im trying to do is that when the user clicked the `edit` button on a specific row, it would get the data from each row, put it in a `<p>Data here</p>` then display it on the same page
what i have done so far is this, i made an onlick function
here is the code for the table in my view

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="detailTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Record ID</th>
            <th>School Year</th>
            <th>School Quarter</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($srs as $key => $vu)
            <tr>
                    <td>{{ $vu->StudentRecordID }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $vu->SchoolYear }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $vu->SchoolQuarter}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $vu->full_name}}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn" id="gid" onclick="tgPanel();" >Edit</button></td>

            </tr>
        @endforeach

    </tbody>

</table>
```

and here is the code in my javascript

```
function tgPanel()
{
   document.getElementById("rid").innerHTML =       document.getElementById("detailTable").rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML ;
   document.getElementById("sy").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("detailTable").rows[0].cells[2].innerHTML ;
   ..and so on..
}
```

well as of now the only thing im getting is the header i dont know how to indicate in the `row[0]`on what row o clicked the button any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onclick function needs a parameter.

```
onclick="tgPanel(this)"
```

Then you can work with the button and get the information.

```
function tgPanel(button) {
    var tr = button.parentElement.parentElement;
}
```